# Duplicate code in similar classes where I cannot add more inheritance

Tags: c#, inheritance

I'm building a .NET Linq-esc query builder for my application and I'm wondering about my implementation and code structure when it comes a few classes.

Basically I'm creating a query builder for SQL, and I need for my classes to be able to using the following behavior:

```
query.Select(...).From(...).Join(...).Where(...);
```

I have created 6 Interfaces that contain one method each that donates what can be done to that class E.G the `Select` class would implement `IFromAble` which contains the method `From(..)`. This allows the behavior above.

This is the same for all of the other classes above and a few more. Some classes, like `Join` will implement a few of the interfaces E.g `IJoinAble, IWhereAble, IOrderAble, IGroupAble, IHavingAble`.

This, as you can imagine will lead to a lot of duplicated code throughout each of my classes.

Each of the classes also implement a common base abstract class, which means I cannot use abstracts to solve the issue.

Is there another way I can implement my intended behavior without all of the duplicated code? Or is this just one of those cases I'm once again tripped up by C#'s single inheritance?

**The Join Class**

```
public class ModuleJoin : QueryModule, IJoinAble, IWhereAble, IOrderAble, IGroupAble
{
    public JoinType JoinType { get; set; }
    public QueryField JoinFrom 
    {
        get { return (QueryField)this.Fields[0]; }
        set { this.Fields[0] = value; } 
    }
    public QueryField JoinTo
    {
        get { return (QueryField)this.Fields[1]; }
        set { this.Fields[1] = value; }
    }

    public ModuleJoin(Query query, JoinType joinType, QueryField joinFrom, QueryField joinTo)
    {
        this.PerentQuery = query;
        this.Fields.Clear();
        this.Fields.Add(joinFrom);
        this.Fields.Add(joinTo);
        JoinType = joinType;
    }

    public ModuleJoin Join(JoinType joinType, QueryField joinFrom, QueryField joinTo)
    {
        ModuleJoin join = new ModuleJoin(this.PerentQuery, joinType, joinFrom, joinTo);
        this.PerentQuery.ModuleJoins.Add(join);
        return join;
    }

    public ModuleWhere Where(IFieldPart itemOne, Comparator comparator, IFieldPart itemTwo)
    {
        ModuleWhere where = new ModuleWhere(this.PerentQuery, itemOne, comparator, itemTwo);
        this.PerentQuery.ModuleWheres.Add(where);
        return where;
    }

    public ModuleGroupBy GroupBy(params IFieldPart[] fields)
    {
        ModuleGroupBy groupBy = new ModuleGroupBy(this.PerentQuery, fields);
        this.PerentQuery.ModuleGroupBy = groupBy;
        return groupBy;
    }
}
```

**QueryModule** (The interface on this just has those properties)

```
public abstract class QueryModule : IQueryModule
{
    public Query PerentQuery { get; set; }
    public FieldCount FieldCount { get; set; }
    public List<IFieldPart> Fields { get; set; }
    public IFieldPart Field
    {
        get { return Fields[0]; }
        set 
        {
            if (Fields.Count == 1)
                Fields[0] = value;
            else
                Fields.Add(value);
        }
    }

    public QueryModule()
    {
        this.Fields = new List<IFieldPart>();
    }
}
```

**IJoinAble** (An example of one of the interfaces)

```
interface IJoinAble
{
    ModuleJoin Join(JoinType joinType, QueryField joinFrom, QueryField joinTo);
}
```

Comment: Have a single class implement all of your interfaces. Where you need a composite interface, use another interface which just inherits from all the interfaces it composes. You'll need at the very most 1 composite interface per method, hopefully fewer

Comment: @LexWebb Normally you can flag your post for migration! But I'll verify on meta

Comment: @LexWebb flagging is the way to go : http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/902/migrating-questions-to-stack-overflow

Comment: This question could be on-topic for Code Review, if you would just include your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting question. The most simple and direct way to approach this problem (not necessarily the wisest) - implement `Select()`, `From()`, `Join()` etc. as extension methods on the interfaces `ISelectable`, `IFromable`, `IJoinable`, etc. The ability to write extension methods to interfaces is a powerful and fascinating language feature with many implications...

Comment: Perfect. I was able to create a single extension class to manage all of the methods for each interface. Thanks.